# How to store the order of element into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, store

I want to store some elements into an array, i need this for the position of each element.

The example below show a simple example what i want to store(notice that the id's will change with every page load).

I want to store the position of each box-parent class with all its children(div)

UPDATE:

The main idea is to get the structure(so the positions of all element) into an array/string, i think its called serialize. The box-parent classes are containers
 for sortable blocks/widgets(box-1, box-2 etc)similar example can be found here http://james.padolsey.com/demo/tut-inettuts-with-cookies/

Basic example

```
    <div id="main-wrapper">

        <div class="box-parent">
            <div id="box-1"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-2"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-3"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-4"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-5"> content here </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-parent">
            <div id="box-6"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-7"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-8"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-9"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-10"> content here </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="box-parent">
            <div id="box-11"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-12"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-13"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-14"> content here </div>
            <div id="box-15"> content here </div>
        </div> 

    </div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to understand your question

Comment: Your proposed output isn't an array, it's an object - and an invalid object because you can't use the same property name twice (or if you do the second one will overwrite the first) so you can't store two different "box-parent" properties in the same object. Perhaps "main-wrapper" should be an actual array (square brackets `[]`) with each element being a "box-parent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure can't be: `object['box-parent']` cannot refer to 2 different values.

You can get the position in various ways. Assuming that each `.box-parent` has 5 elements, you can apply the following calculation:

```
var elem; // given that elem refers to a "box-X", for instance $('#box-4'):
elem.prevAll().length + elem.parent().prevAll('.box-parent').length*5
```

You can also enumerate over `.box-parent` with an external counter, and put the positions into a structure:

```
var i=0;
$('.box-parent').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        // i = the position
        // ...            

        i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: No the structure is a sortable grid, so the number of div's will change.

Comment: So use the other method to enumerate over them.

Answer (score 0):

Use getElementsByTag(), count the elements that don't have a class of "box-parent", and set "position" equal to the count of non-"box-parent" class elements.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this correctly you have a structure like this

```
<container>
    <element class="parent">
        <!-- Content #1 -->
    </element>
    <element class="parent">
        <!-- Content #2 -->
    </element>
    <element class="parent">
        <!-- Content #3 -->
</container>
```

and you are defining that the element with content #1 is the first element and it increases downward and you would like to preserve that order.

I'm assuming that jQuery is acceptable; if it's not let me know

```
// Something like this should work
$("container").children(".parent")
// [Element, Element, Element]
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCP6d/)